# SUMIF: formula as criteria not working for entire column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

My worksheet contains orders from clients. The orders are all wooden panels.

[image: IMG: Section of the sheet with attempted formula]

Every order is assigned a number which is led by the letter Q.

- Column B contains the number of parts in the order.
- Column C contains the total m² in the order.

Orders that contain one or more parts that are **2.8 x 0.0735 m** will get a row of their own.

I'm trying to count the number of times that this part occurs in a list of more than a thousand rows.

So if I divide the **total m²** by the **m² of the part I'm looking for** and divide this by **the amount of parts in the order**, I should get exactly **1** as a result.
If I take the sum of all the number of parts that result in a 1, I get my total.

Now I'd like to put this in one formula for the entire worksheet, but SUMIF doesn't work the way I'm trying. (It's in Dutch)

```
=SOM.ALS(B:B;(C:C/(2,8*0,0735)/B:B)=1)
```

I can't seem to use this formula as a criterium in the SUMIF.

For now I use a helping column that gives the right amount per row. Then take the total SUM of these.

Is it possible to put this in a single formula?

Comment: SUMIF only sums up rows where the criteria range (B:B) matches the value you specify. Your formula makes no sense in that context, since you are creating an array of True/False values as the criteria, and there are no True/False values in column B.

Comment: Not sure what your outcome should be but maybe try: `=SOMPRODUCT(ALS.FOUT((C:C/(2,8*0,0735)/B:B)=1;0)*B:B)` or in English: `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((C:C/(2.8*0.0735)/B:B)=1,0)*B:B)`

Comment: @BRTN, did my answer work? I'm happy to work on it if it didn't meet your needs. Just let me know.

Comment: @JvdV I tried it, but it didn't do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dutch and English:

```
{=SOMPRODUCT(--(B:B=(ALS(ISTEKST(C:C);1;C:C))/(2,8*0,0735));B:B)}


{=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B=(IF(ISTEXT(C:C),1,C:C))/(2.8*0.0735)),B:B)}
```

is working perfectly. (Enter with Ctrl-Shift-Enter)

The first bit is the logical test, which will check if B:B = C:C / (2.8*0.0735)

It got stuck on #VALUE! because there is text in C:C.
The IF(ISTEXT)) eliminates text by converting them to numeric values, in this case **1**, but it can be any numeric value.

The logical test will return TRUE(1) or FALSE(0) because of the double dash or unary operator and this will be multiplied by their respective B:B value.

Because the row with text has no value in B:B, it will result as zero.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to come up with a solution! That's really the best possible outcome here.
One thing, since you used `=SUMPRODUCT()` or `=SOMPRODUCT()`  you probably don't need to confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter. It works without it on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Try this one:

`{=SUM(--(B:B=C:C/(2.8*0.0735))*IF(ISERROR(1/B:B),0,1))}`

Remember to enter it as an array function with CNTRL + SHIFT + ENTER.

The first half of the formula is just a logical test, after the asterisk it tests if 1/B results in an error (thereby omitting text, zeroes, and blanks) and returns a zero if there is an error.

These are then summed and the result displayed.

Comment: I just tried it, I get the error _"You've Entered Too Few Arguments For This Function"_. What does the double dash do? I'll keep searching along your formula too. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting somewhere with your idea.
For now I'm at this formula: 
`=SOMPRODUCT(--(B:B=C:C/(2,8*0,0735)))-SOMPRODUCT(--(B:B="");--(C:C=""))` or in English I guess 
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B=C:C/(2.8*0.0735)))-SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B=""),--(C:C=""))`

This counts the amount of rows that contain the part I want. Now I still need to multiply this with the right amount of parts in the orders. The last part is to omit empty cells. I doesn't yet omit text, so for now I deleted this manually.

Comment: Update: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B=C:C/(2.8*0.0735));B:B)` 
works perfectly on the condition that column C doesn't contain any text.

Comment: I've got it & I'll post it as an answer. Your suggestion brought me on the right track though, couldn't have found it without.